# Private Network broken in Vagrant with Docker

Tags: linux, networking, vagrant, archlinux, docker

I create a Virtualbox vm via Vagrant by using the default [Docker Vagrantfile](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/Vagrantfile). Building the vm with `vagrant up` works as expected and provides a running box to work with.

I then needed the ability to forward ports and added the following to the `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant::VERSION >= "1.1.0" and Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, :host => 5432, :guest => 5432 # postgres
  # ... more port forwardings
end
```

This works, but i then realized that i need port forwarding in both directions. I tried to create a private network for this matter instead of forwarding each port. The following addition to the config should have done the trick:

```
Vagrant::VERSION >= "1.1.0" and Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.17.0.2"
end
```

But, this triggers an error while creating the vm:

```
> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

**Any idea how to debug and resolve this?**

*Host OS: Arch Linux*

*VM OS: Ubuntu (see Vagrantfile linked above)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Load_the_VirtualBox_kernel_modules):**

> To ensure full functionality of bridged networking, ensure that the
>   `vboxnetadp`, `vboxnetflt` and `vboxpci` kernel modules are loaded too and
>   that the `net-tools` package is installed.

### Kernel modules

The issue is that the kernel modules for creating private networks in a virtual machine need to be loaded seperately:

```
sudo modprobe -a vboxnetadp vboxnetflt
```

To make this change permanent after each reboot, put the following lines in `/etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf`:

```
vboxdrv
vboxnetadp
vboxnetflt
```

### Packages

`net-tools` needs to be installed:

```
sudo pacman -S net-tools
```

You also need the `virtualbox-host-modules` package in order to bring private networks to life:

```
sudo pacman -S virtualbox-host-modules
```